# How to explode an string which is basically an array of arrays and store it in separate rows in redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I Have a table something like :

| id | col2 | col_3 | col_4 | array_string |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | .. | .. | .. | [[h1,r1],[h2,r2],[h3,r3]] |

i want o/p as

| id | col2 | col_3 | col_4 | col_h | col_r |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | .. | .. | .. | h1 | r1 |
| 1 | .. | .. | .. | h2 | r2 |
| 1 | .. | .. | .. | h3 | r3 |

Column `array_string` is stored as a string and not a super or json type data type and  it can consist of any number of elements (for example, here i have used an array with only three-element)
I tried `split_part`, `string_to_array` but was still unable to solve the problem.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Problem with split_part is that i have to manually select parts n number of times . and since i dont know how many elements can be present in  the column  I am stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to convert the string to a "super" data type using json_parse() - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/JSON_PARSE.html

And then unnest the array using PartiQL syntax now supported for this process - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/query-super.html

You case looks to be nearly identical to some of the examples so I won't repeat them here.

Comment: json_parse didnt help.  gave error : `Invalid character: [[h1,1],[h2 (82 bytes skipped)`

Comment: So it does have to be a valid json string.  You will need quotes around text values - [["h1",1],["h2", ...

Comment: how to do that ,any idea  ?

Comment: It depends on the syntax of the string - what are the rules?  Is it alway an array of 2 value arrays?  Is the first always text and the second alway an INT?  I think you can likely make the quoting changes with regexp_replace(), adding double quotes to all the fields - making everything strings (or just the first field).  The complexity will depend on how loose or tight the rules are for this column.  If some values follow one set of rules and others, a different set then this get more complex quickly.

Comment: yes , it will always be a array of 2 elements and first wil be string and second will be int

Comment: I'm guessing you need help with the regex - I made a sql fiddle (postgres) for you to see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/b6978/2.  Redshift will be slightly different in that you don't need the ,'g' argument for Redshift -  regexp_replace(array_string, '\[([^,[]*),','["\1",')

Comment: Thanks for the regex , but i am getting an error ` Found a closing ) with no corresponding openening parenthesis. The error occurred while parsing the regular expression: '[([^,[]*>>>HERE>>>),'.`

Comment: Looks like StackOverflow ate the backslash.  Check out the SQL fiddle.  I'll try again to get things to post correctly in the comment.  regexp_replace(array_string, '\[([^,[]*),','["\1",')

Comment: Nope - ate it again.  let's try it this way regexp_replace(array_string, '<backslash here>[([^,[]*),','["\1",')

Comment: Still the same issue , i tried with the same regex that you pased in sql fiddle too but with 'g' removed same error.

Comment: `regexp_replace(array_string,'\[([^,[]*),','["\1",')`

Comment: passed double slash and it is working now,
`regexp_replace(array_string,'\\[([^,[]*),','["\\1",') `

Comment: Oh the fun we have with backslashes

Answer (score 2):

This is a Postgres solution that may not work on Redhsift or may need to be touched.
Here is an illustration how to expand your string:

```sql
with t(a) as
(
  select jsonb_array_elements(regexp_replace(
    '[[h1,r1],[h2,r2],[h3,r3]]', '\y', '"', 'g')::jsonb)
)
select a->>0 col_h, a->>1 col_r from t;
```

| col_h | col_r |
| --- | --- |
| h1 | r1 |
| h2 | r2 |
| h3 | r3 |

The whole query will be

```sql
select t.id, t.col2, t.col_3, t.col_4, l.*
from the_table t
cross join lateral
(
 with t2(a) as
 (
  select jsonb_array_elements(regexp_replace(t.array_string,'\y','"','g')::jsonb)
 )
 select a->>0 col_h, a->>1 col_r from t2
) l;
```

Comment: unfortunately, jsonb is not supported in redshift –